# Problems with Responsiveness

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I did in my project accessibility button but I have problem with the Responsiveness of the Button. I can't see the menu in screens untill the size 1300px and and even then there is a problem 'cuz the the menu became bigger the bigger the screen. What can I do the solve this?

Here's the code of the menu:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../../../css/AccessibilityMenu.css";

const AccessibilityMenu = ({
  style,
  onToggleDarkMode,
  onToggleTextOnly,
  onToggleAnimations,
  onToggleLinkHighlight,
}) => {
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(16);

  const fontFamilies = [
    { name: "Arial", text: " מעבר לפונט אריאל" },
    { name: "Times New Roman", text: "מעבר לפונט טיימס ניו רומן" },
    { name: "Verdana", text: "מעבר לפונט ורדנה " },
  ];

  const increaseLineSpacing = () => {
    const bodyStyles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
    const currentFontSize = parseFloat(bodyStyles.fontSize);
    const currentLineSpacing =
      parseFloat(bodyStyles.lineHeight) / currentFontSize;
    const newLineSpacing = currentLineSpacing + 0.2;
    document.body.style.lineHeight = `${newLineSpacing}`;
  };

  const decreaseLineSpacing = () => {
    const bodyStyles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
    const currentFontSize = parseFloat(bodyStyles.fontSize);
    const currentLineSpacing =
      parseFloat(bodyStyles.lineHeight) / currentFontSize;
    const newLineSpacing = currentLineSpacing - 0.2;
    document.body.style.lineHeight = `${newLineSpacing}`;
  };

  const increaseTextSize = () => {
    setFontSize((prevFontSize) => {
      const newFontSize = prevFontSize + 2;
      document.documentElement.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
      console.log("New Font Size:", newFontSize);
      return newFontSize;
    });
  };

  const decreaseTextSize = () => {
    setFontSize((prevFontSize) => {
      const newFontSize = prevFontSize - 2;
      document.documentElement.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
      console.log("New Font Size:", newFontSize);
      return newFontSize;
    });
  };

  const changeFontFamily = (fontFamily) => {
    document.body.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
  };

  const changeTextColor = (color) => {
    document.body.style.color = color;
  };

  const toggleHeaderHighlight = () => {
    const headers = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
    headers.forEach((header) => {
      header.classList.toggle("highlighted-header");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="accessibility-menu" style={style}>
      <button onClick={increaseTextSize}>הגדל טקסט</button>
      <button onClick={decreaseTextSize}>הקטן טקסט</button>
      <button onClick={onToggleDarkMode}>מצב לילה</button>
      <button onClick={onToggleTextOnly}>מצב טקסט בלבד</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeTextColor("black")}>טקסט שחור</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeTextColor("blue")}>טקסט כחול</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeTextColor("red")}>טקסט אדום</button>
      <button onClick={onToggleLinkHighlight}>הדגש קישורים</button>
      <button onClick={toggleHeaderHighlight}>סמן כותרות</button>

      <div className="font-family-buttons">
        {fontFamilies.map((fontFamily) => (
          <button
            key={fontFamily.name}
            onClick={() => changeFontFamily(fontFamily.name)}
          >
            {fontFamily.text}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={increaseLineSpacing}>הגדל רווח בין שורות</button>
      <button onClick={decreaseLineSpacing}>הקטן רווח בין שורות</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccessibilityMenu;
```

Ans this is the code of the css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accessibility-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.accessibility-menu button {
  background-color: #4a90e2;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px;
}

body.dark-mode {
  background-color: #333;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body.dark-mode a {
  color: red;
}

/* High contrast mode */
body.high-contrast {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

body.high-contrast a {
  color: #000;
}

/* Text-only mode */
body.text-only * {
  background: none !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

body.text-only img {
  display: none !important;
}

body.text-only *::before,
body.text-only *::after {
  content: none !important;
}

.font-family-buttons button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.highlight-links {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.highlighted-header {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.zoomed-element {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

:root {
  --animation-speed: 1s;
}

.some-animation {
  animation-duration: var(--animation-speed);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .accessibility-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .accessibility-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .accessibility-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1215px) {
  .accessibility-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1216px) {
  .accessibility-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

And this is the code of the button itself:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import "../../../css/AccessibilityButton.css";
import AccessibilityMenu from "./AccessibilityMenu";

const AccessibilityButton = (props) => {
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);
  const [menuStyle, setMenuStyle] = useState({});

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMenuVisible((prevVisible) => !prevVisible);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  const toggleAnimations = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("animation-active");
  };

  const toggleLinkHighlight = () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    links.forEach((link) => {
      link.classList.toggle("highlight-links");
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const buttonElement = document.querySelector(".accessibility-button");
    if (buttonElement) {
      const rect = buttonElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      setMenuStyle({
        position: "absolute",
        top: `${rect.bottom}px`,
        left: `${rect.left}px`,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  };

  const toggleTextOnly = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("text-only");
  };

  const changeColors = (bgColor, textColor) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    document.body.style.color = textColor;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="accessibility-button"
        onClick={handleClick}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        aria-label={props.ariaLabel}
        tabIndex={0}
      >
        תפריט נגישות
      </button>
      {menuVisible &&
        createPortal(
          <AccessibilityMenu
            style={menuStyle}
            onToggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
            onToggleTextOnly={toggleTextOnly}
            onChangeColors={changeColors}
            onToggleAnimations={toggleAnimations}
            onToggleLinkHighlight={toggleLinkHighlight}
          />,
          document.body
        )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AccessibilityButton;
```

And this is the code of the css of the button itslef:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accessibility-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accessibility-button:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .accessibility-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```